# Interfaces y entidades en Angular y Entity Framework

Tags: angular, entity-framework, webapi

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación angular que hace peticiones a una api hecha con Visual Studio (entity framework y web api).
Tengo entidades que son complejas, ejemplo, una Vendedor que dentro tiene un objeto perfil, un objeto Domicilio etc...
Estas entidades al obtenerlas con angular las tengo que meter un un modelo Persona (interface) escrito en angular...y es tedioso tener que hacer esta interface, y las interfaces que contiene, saben si existe alguna herramienta que con el modelo de entity framework te cree las interfaces en c#, muchas gracias.

Comment: Siempre puedes usar `objeto:any` en angular...

Comment: pero si la api me trae un objeto gigante, json, y lo declaro como any, no voy a poder acceder a persona.Perfil.idPerfil por ejemplo, lo tengo que parsear a algo, como accedo a los campos(atributos) facilmente?

Comment: Con una interfaz. Hasta cierto punto, es mas fácil mantener muchas interfaces pequeñas. Aunque el schema de tu BD sea muy grande cada operación puede tener la estructura necesaria y cada consulta cargar solo los parametros que necesite (aunque no rellenes toda la interfaz).  También sería bueno que evaluaras si para ese caso en especifico requieres un objeto tan grande.

Comment: Sucede que uso Automapper y con este se obtiene el objeto completo y sus subobjetos, igualmente no me parece mal tener todos los datos a mano, no es taaaaan grande en este caso...

Comment: Imprime el `json` que recibes y copia ese objeto a un archivo nuevo de visual code. Limpialo y conviertelo en una interfaz. Es lo que hago yo. De esta manera no ocupas hacer sub-archivos hasta que lo vayas requiriendo.

Comment: Vos decis de un objeto json grande, generar uno solo a mano? sin sub interfaces??
como creas la interface con sub objetos?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que encontré la solución, en vez de C# a TypeScript puedo hacer, desde JSON (el que te devuelve la petición a la api) a TypeScript (Interface)
http://json2ts.com/
Gracias por su ayuda